# Complex SQL query to fetch all objects that are connected to all possible unique objects

Tags: sql

Consider the following schema

```
Athlete (**AID**, name, age, *nationality*)
Competition (**CID**,*discipline*, sport) 
Venue (**VID**, name, address, seats) 
Participation(**athlete**, **competition**, **venue**)
```

I need to make an SQL query to answer the following question. The answer should contain only standard SQL features (select, join, where etc should be enough). In addition if you explain why your solution works and how that would be very much appreciated!

> Which countries (*nationality*) are participating in all
>   *disciplines*?

Thanks
EDIT:
Example that will help to understand the expected output:
So imagine we have the following Sport disciplines: **Martial Arts, Water sports, Athletics**. AND countries like **USA, Germany, France**. And it can happen that USA only has athletes for Water sports and athletics but not for Martial arts. So USA should be excluded from the answer. SQL query should bring only the list of countries (Nationality) that has at least one athlete in every single Discipline there.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: We're happy to help with homework questions but only if you make some effort upfront, i.e. write a basic SQL statement

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid not sure what you mean... but we had some basic introduction to sql course... this was in the exam question. so i was able to answer almost all questions but not this one and when i asked the professor to know the answer after the exam he rejected that... now i am asking it here just for my curiosity.

Comment: Is there a Country/Nationality table? Seems like there should be.

Comment: @Yatrix No,... Every athlete has information on his/her nationality in the table Athlete

Comment: In that case, there _should_ be for a good database design. ;)

Comment: @Yatrix sure agree with you, but this was done to make exam harder haha and it is a fun puzzle guess

Comment: You should set up the tables in a sqlfiddle - it'll help folks work through this with you a lot easier. May also help you visualize the problem yourself too.